# Calling a static method using generics or FooClass.CLASS?

Tags: java, generics, static

I have the following base class

```
public class Car
{
   public static int getWheelsCount()
   {
       return 4;
   }
}
```

Then I have a few child classes extending from it with custom methods, e.g `Honda extends Car`, `Mercedes extends Car`, etc.

In a separate method, I simply want to be able to receive a particular sub-child of `Car` , either as generics or `Honda.CLASS` and call the `getWheelsCount()` method of it. Something like this:

```
public void doSomething<T extends Car>()
{
    int wheels = T.getWheelsCount();
}
```

Or:

```
public void doSomething(Car myCar.CLASS)
{
    int wheels = myCar.getWheelsCount();
}
```

I could call this function in this way:

```
doSomething<Honda>();
doSomething<Mercedes>();
```

or:

```
doSomething(Honda.CLASS);
doSomething(Mercedes.CLASS);
```

etc.

Any ideas how I can accomplish what I want here?

Comment: `.CLASS` is `.class`, right?

Comment: Why don't you just do `Honda.doSomething()`?

Comment: What is the problem here a little confused

Comment: @CoderOfHonor Because `doSomething` is part of a different class, I don't want to copy it over to `Honda`, `Mercedes`, and every other car, etc.

Comment: @WChargin not sure what you mean, but it is a java.lang.Class

Comment: Do you not have objects to pass into your method?

Comment: @Aurand Yes exactly, its a static method, so I'd rather if I could just pass the type of the class than have to make a new instance of the object and pass it.

Comment: @ClickUpvote `String.class` compiles; `String.CLASS` does not.

Comment: Does the subclass not inherit the method?

Comment: @WChargin I can use either, whichever will get the job done.

Comment: @CoderOfHonor No, each class has its own implementation. (The actual classes are not cars, I'm just using cars as an example to make this simple)

Comment: Java does not allow overriding `static` methods, so I don't see how your scenario is even possible. If we knew what you were actually trying to do (instead of your attempt to solve that problem), there might be a way to sidestep the issue altogether. Otherwise, this question is very hard to answer.

Comment: @JakeKing I didn't know that statics can't be overriden, fair enough. Feel free to post that as answer and i'll accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, static methods cannot be overridden. This is mostly due to the fact that Java classes are not objects themselves, unlike a language like Objective-C, for example. Java class objects (instances of `java.lang.Class`) are wholly different things that are only part of Java's somewhat hacky reflection system.

While it's hard to give much advice without understand your purpose, I would advise that you attempt to eliminate static functionality from your Java classes as much as possible due to this limitation, unless the methods in question are utility or helper methods. Try to restructure your code to pass instances instead of classes.

With more information about the *goal*, rather than purely information about the problem you've had in implementing your particular solution, it may be easier to give a more specific and comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 3):

Since the static method is declared on `Car`, just always call:

```
Car.getWheelsCount();
```

Obviously, you don't mean for the method to be static, you want it to be a regular method, and have each car give it's answer independantly.... so, remove the 'static' from the method declaration, and have each Car subclass override the method.... then call the instance method for each car.

Comment: I don't want to have to make a new instance of the object each time, that's why I'd rather do it as a static method.

Comment: @ClickUpvote: what do you mean "you don't want to make a new instance each time? You won't **need** the method unless you've already got an instance, so this comment makes little sense.

Comment: The reason why its a static method is so I won't need an instance. E.g if I want to validate how many wheels a car has, I can just check that by doing `Handa.getWheelCount()` instead of `honda = new Honda(); honda.getWheelCount()`